# What is the odbcjt32.dll real path, System32 or SysWOW64 to check it's parameters

Tags: c#, ms-access, odbc, ms-jet-ace

I'm trying to create a ODBC connection programmatic, via registry.

When using Windows ODBC tool, I noticed that for ODBC 32, "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)" is using odbcjt32.dll and the entry in registry would point to this location:

```
"Driver"="C:\\Windows\\system32\\odbcjt32.dll"
```

But when I search for the file, it exists, but is located in other folder:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64
```

I need to know why because:

- I need to create connection from C#, I presume I should put the entry like ODBC tool does, to C:\Windows\system32
- I want to check this DLL version from C#, so I should check C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcjt32.dll ??

There is a magic redirection for this DLL in Windows ?

Thanks for clarification,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the super user question "System32 and SysWOW64 on Windows 7"](https://superuser.com/questions/281730/system32-and-syswow64-on-windows-7/284701#284701) for some background info on SysWoW64 and system32. So yes, there is a "magic redirection" on windows for 32 bit and 64 bit DLLs.

The file odbcjt32.dll in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 is a 32 bit version. The path C:\Windows\system32\ is redirected to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ for a 32 bit program. What is the current solution platfrom of your program? x86, x64 or Any CPU? I think it should be x86 so that it can use the 32 bit driver.

Take a look at `Environment.GetFolderPath` method with `Environment.SpecialFolder.SystemX86` so that you do not need to hardcode the path.

**Additional info on the magic redirection**

To see the bitness of a DLL you can use `dumpbin`.I use "odbc32.dll" in my examples below. Open the `Developer Command Prompt` of your Visual Studio version and execute the following command:

```
dumpbin /headers c:\windows\syswow64\odbc32.dll
```

The output will contain the following line:

```
FILE HEADER VALUES
             14C machine (x86)
```

Now execute dumpbin for the DLL in the `system32` directory:

```
dumpbin /headers c:\windows\system32\odbc32.dll
```

which outputs

```
FILE HEADER VALUES
            8664 machine (x64)
```

As you can see there is a x64 ("64 bit") and a x86 ("32 bit") version of the same DLL on the machine. Windows does the magic redirection depending on the bitness of the program that is running. A 64 bit program gets the DLL from C:\Windows\system32 and a 32 bit program gets it from C:\Windows\SysWoW64.

Answer (score 1):

But why create a DSN?

You can do this:

```
string MyCon = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};dbq=C:\\Test2\\test44.accdb";
DataTable MyTable = new DataTable();
OdbcDataAdapter MyData = new OdbcDataAdapter("select * from tblHotels", MyCon);
MyData.Fill(MyTable);

MessageBox.Show("Records = " + MyTable.Rows.Count.ToString() );
```

We only need:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;
```

I mean, your utility might be  wanting to create a DSN, but if you just looking to create a connection, then the above is fine. As long as ACE32, or ACE 64 bit version is installed, then this will work.

Note that odbcjt32.dll is a x32 bit ONLY component. You will never find or see a x64 bit version - it don't exist. And installing ACE x64 will not install that .dll either.

However, it not clear why you need to create the DSN connection as opposed to having a setting in your application (or some setup file) that simply has the above connection string? Attempting to create a DSN will often require elevated rights, but in place of the DSN you can use a simple connection string for ODBC as per above. There is no speical references required for the above code snip to work - it just uses the ODBC parts built into the net framework.

Comment: Agree :)) But I create a application to show what drivers I have on machine. This is because some CAD program needs ODBC... long story :). But thank you anyhow!

Comment: Ok. Then just keep in mind there  is no x64 bit version of that .dll, and installing ACE of either bit size version does not install that .dll. So you never will find a x64 bit version of that .dll